# Download a report generated from mysql in pdf format in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, download

I want to download the following report in PDF format in PHP

[image]

[image]

When I get the report using some query to list the business details,it will show the result as in Image1.Now I want to get the report which is rounded as red mark marked in Image2 in PDF format with the company logo and some details.Kindly help me to get my result.

Answer (score 1):

Use [phpToPDF](http://phptopdf.com/) library it's simple to use for creating pdf

```
 <?php
    require('phpToPDF.php');

    //Your HTML in a variable
    $my_html="<HTML><h2>PDF from HTML using phpToPDF</h2></HTML>";

    //Set Your Options -- we are saving the PDF as 'my_filename.pdf' to a 'my_pdfs' folder
    $pdf_options = array(
      "source_type" => 'html',
      "source" => $my_html,
      "action" => 'save',
      "save_directory" => 'my_pdfs',
      "file_name" => 'my_filename.pdf');

    //Code to generate PDF file from options above
    phptopdf($pdf_options);
?>
```

Comment: what is phpToPDF.php @Jivani Jaydeep?

Comment: it's library file to convert html to pdf you can get that file after you create account on phptopdf.com

Comment: ok i have downloaded that file and then inserted that api key...but when i try to execute that code after a button click,it does not working

Comment: have you put that file in same folder as your php file.